# Find out if the column supports "Null" values in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli

I have a mysql database of 100's of tables. Some columns allow null value, some don't.
I am inserting data into the table dynamically in php mysqli. I am using the following code to insert any null values:

`$value = ($value == "") ? null : $value;`

But, the problem with this is I am getting `Column 'XXX' cannot be null` error. How can I determine if the column supports Null values?

Please help.

Comment: do you want a one-time solution so you'll know which columns allow null, or a code you'll be able to use before each INSERT?

Comment: preferably, a code that I can use before each insert. The thing is, I am importing data into the database, and I am writing php scripts to automize the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all information you need about database structure through the database `information_schema`, like this one (you want the column `IS_NULLABLE`):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  AND table_schema = 'db_name'
  AND column_name = 'col_name'
```

Reference:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

Comment: Thanks mate. This seems to be working fine, as of now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In your database set the DEFAULT value "" (empty string) for fields wich IS NOT NULL. So if you insert NULL value the MySQL will substitute it with default "".

OR

```
SHOW COLUMNS FOR `table_name`;
```

Look at field named `Null`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info from `information_schema` database (**IS_NULLABLE** field)-

```
SELECT
  TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, IS_NULLABLE
FROM
  information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'; -- specify your filter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name_here`
```

Which will give you something like the following output:

```
Field  Type              Null  Key  Default  Extra
id     int(10) unsigned  NO    PRI  NULL     auto_increment
name   varchar(200)      YES        NULL
```

If you have access to the table `information_schema`, you can do:

```
SELECT IS_NULLABLE
FROM   COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_NAME   = "table name"
AND    TABLE_SCHEMA = "db_name"
AND    COLUMN_NAME  = "column name"
LIMIT  1
```

(I've edited the following query to add the TABLE_SCHEMA column from Doug's accepted answer, in case anyone finds this answer later)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't blindly translate an empty string to mysql NULL at all.
That's actually 2 different values, each have it's distinct features - so, swapping them may lead to unpredictable results.

The same goes for the trading PHP's NOLL into Mysql' NULL. They may have different meaning too.